# how to replace 1,2,3,4,5 with 1-5 using vb.net c#?

Tags: c#, vb.net, numbers

I have a list of ID which is integer.

Those ID some part are sequence, some not.

For example, the IDs are 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 7, 8, 9.

How can i show them become 1-5,7-9 using a function in vb.net or c#?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Is the list ordered? If not order it. Then walk through the list looking for runs of consecutive values. When the runs break, well you know what to do.

Comment: Use it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13628124/seperate-range-of-numbers-if-in-sequence-by-hyphen-and-if-break-in-sequence-occu

Comment: Thanks. Problem solve.